# Remove object from NSMutableArray in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary

I'm making a way to create cells with the checkmark. I have a problem!

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSString *keyOfMainDic = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableArray *temDic = [rilievi objectForKey:keyOfMainDic];

UITableViewCell * thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
     NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray *selArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
     {
         thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         [sendRelief setObject: temDic forKey: keyOfMainDic];
         [selArray addObject: sendRelief];
     }
     else
     {
         thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         [selArray removeObject:sendRelief];
     }
```

- **selArray** is a `NSMutableArray`
- **keyOfMainDic** contains the key of another dictionary
- **temDic** is a `NSMutableArray`, because through the keyOfMainDic key, in the other dictionary I have a variable number of values

Basically, this method works like this: when I click on a cell in my `UITableView` I extract the previous dictionary key (which corresponds to the element displayed in the `UITableView`.) By using this key, I extract the actual values of that key, so in these first two variables, I'm going to extract the single key that interests me and its values.

At this point what I do is this: I create a new dictionary (dict) and a new `NSMutableArray` (selArray).
If `thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`, then I put a checkmark on that cell because I have selected it and at the same time add a new object (**temDic**) with the **keyOfMainDic** key (the two previous variables) to the dictionary. Then I add this first dictionary to a `NSMutableArray` and repeat the operation the cells I care about in `UITableView`.

This work.

The problem is to do the opposite. When I click on a cell that has the checkmark, I remove the checkmark and try to remove that dictionary from the selArray because I just do not want to consider that cell anymore. This I do with `[selArray removeObject: sendRelief];` but it does not work and I do not know how to delete the dictionary by selecting a cell from the `UITableView`.

selArray I create it just because I need a compact structure that I'll have to send to another controller.

I hope I explained myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do but you're saying that the selArray is supposed to track all checked items? In this case, it looks like it would be reinitialized every time this method is called. I would assume the remove would never work because it would alway be empty each time this method is called because selArray gets reinitialized each time. So maybe try turning selArray into an @property.

Comment: @R.Lin I really can do it as you suggest, but I have only one problem. When I go back the UITableView remains with the selected checkmark cells. How do I do to remove checkmarks every time I go into the UITableViewController?

Comment: It's hard to say not being able to see your code, but I would think that you are also setting the checkmark in cellForRowAtIndexPath? I would use the selArray as the basis for setting the checkmarks in cellForRowAtIndex path and if you want to clear the checkmarks then clear the selArray on maybe viewWillAppear?

Comment: But..if I clear the selArray in viewWillAppear, the array is empty but the checkmark remain..Basically I have two roads. **1)** I select the cells I'm interested in with a checkmark and send selArray to the other controller. But when I go back I have to find ways to clear the checkmarks. (the array we said we empty it in the viewwillappear method. **2)** I have to find ways to delete objects in selArray in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method based on the checkmark that I'm going to deselect

Comment: I can’t really follow what is going on with all of these arrays and dictionaries, but your approach seems way too complicated. If your rows cannot be reordered then a simple approach is to use a `Set<IndexPath>` to store the index paths of the checked rows. Then, in `cellForRowAt` you simply check whether the current indexPath is in the set and set/clear the cell accessory accordingly. The same in `didSelect`; add or remove the indexPath according to whether it is in the set or not and reload the row

Comment: @Lucatom I agree with Paulw that your approach seems complicated but as for the checkmarks still staying. I am assuming that this is on some sort of nav stack and the checkmarks are still being retained when you pop back to this view. If you are not explicitly setting the checks in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are only seeing the the checks based on what's being remembered by the UI. This will be bad if you're doing cell reuse, which you probably are. Make sure to set the check based on your selArray in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Ehi guys, I've been solved. I wrote `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Every time I go back to the UITableViewController checkmarks are deleted and I can make a new selection and I can create a new array to ship to the next controller! If either of you responds to the question, I still give you the best answer